# Odoo 14 > Field "holiday_status_id" does not exist in model "res.config.settings"

Tags: python, xml, xpath, odoo, odoo-14

I am using Odoo 14 and get the below error when installing a custom module for automatic leave allocation. This is a module that is working in Odoo 12. I cant figure out where I am going wrong. want to create a new two fields under Settings > Employee > Work Organization.

```
Field "holiday_status_id" does not exist in model "res.config.settings"

View name: res.config.settings.view.form.inherit.hr.auto.leaves
Error context:
 view: ir.ui.view(565,)
 xmlid: res_config_settings_view_form
 view.model: res.config.settings
 view.parent: ir.ui.view(477,)
 file: c:\users\training\desktop\odoo14\venv\scripts\odoo\addons\hr_auto_leaves\views\res_config_settings_views.xml


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Training\Desktop\odoo14\venv\Scripts\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "C:\Users\Training\Desktop\odoo14\venv\Scripts\odoo\http.py", line 683, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "C:\Users\Training\Desktop\odoo14\venv\Scripts\odoo\http.py", line 359, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Training\Desktop\odoo14\venv\Scripts\odoo\service\model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Training\Desktop\odoo14\venv\Scripts\odoo\http.py", line 347, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Training\Desktop\odoo14\venv\Scripts\odoo\http.py", line 912, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Training\Desktop\odoo14\venv\Scripts\odoo\http.py", line 531, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Training\Desktop\odoo14\venv\Scripts\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1381, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Training\Desktop\odoo14\venv\Scripts\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1369, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Training\Desktop\odoo14\venv\Scripts\odoo\api.py", line 396, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Training\Desktop\odoo14\venv\Scripts\odoo\api.py", line 383, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-71>", line 2, in button_immediate_install
  File "C:\Users\Training\Desktop\odoo14\venv\Scripts\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 73, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Training\Desktop\odoo14\venv\Scripts\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 474, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)
  File "C:\Users\Training\Desktop\odoo14\venv\Scripts\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 592, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "C:\Users\Training\Desktop\odoo14\venv\Scripts\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 89, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "C:\Users\Training\Desktop\odoo14\venv\Scripts\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 455, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "C:\Users\Training\Desktop\odoo14\venv\Scripts\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 348, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "C:\Users\Training\Desktop\odoo14\venv\Scripts\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 221, in load_module_graph
    load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package)
  File "C:\Users\Training\Desktop\odoo14\venv\Scripts\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 69, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind)
  File "C:\Users\Training\Desktop\odoo14\venv\Scripts\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 733, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate)
  File "C:\Users\Training\Desktop\odoo14\venv\Scripts\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 799, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot())
  File "C:\Users\Training\Desktop\odoo14\venv\Scripts\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 719, in parse
    self._tag_root(de)
  File "C:\Users\Training\Desktop\odoo14\venv\Scripts\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 685, in _tag_root
    )) from e
Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Training\Desktop\odoo14\venv\Scripts\odoo\http.py", line 639, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "C:\Users\Training\Desktop\odoo14\venv\Scripts\odoo\http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing file:/c:/users/training/desktop/odoo14/venv/scripts/odoo/addons/hr_auto_leaves/views/res_config_settings_views.xml:3, near
<record id="res_config_settings_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">res.config.settings.view.form.inherit.hr.auto.leaves</field>
        <field name="model">res.config.settings</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="70"/>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.res_config_settings_view_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//div[@name='work_organization_setting_container']" position="inside">
                <div class="o_setting_right_pane">
                    <field name="auto_leave_allocation"/>
                </div>
                <div class="o_setting_right_pane">
                    <label for="auto_leave_allocation"/>
                    <div class="text-muted">
                        Automatic allocation of leave to the new employees.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//div[@id='default_company_schedule_setting']" position="inside">
                <div class="o_setting_left_pane">
                    <label for="holiday_status_id"/>
                    <div class="content-group">
                        <div class="mt16">
                            <field name="holiday_status_id" widget="many2many_tags" placeholder="Select Leave Type"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Here is my res_config_settings.py file. Here I have inherit table 'res.config.settings'. and I want to create two new fields which are holiday_status_id and auto_leave_allocation. Please help me out.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import fields, models


class ResConfigSettings(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'res.config.settings'

    holiday_status_id = fields.Many2many('hr.leave.type', string="Leave Types")
    auto_leave_allocation = fields.Boolean(string="Automatic Leave Allocation")
```

And here is the view file. In the view file, I believe that I have wrote the xpath correctly. I really cant figure out where I am going wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="res_config_settings_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">res.config.settings.view.form.inherit.hr.auto.leaves</field>
        <field name="model">res.config.settings</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="70"/>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.res_config_settings_view_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//div[@name='work_organization_setting_container']" position="inside">
                <div class="o_setting_right_pane">
                    <field name="auto_leave_allocation"/>
                </div>
                <div class="o_setting_right_pane">
                    <label for="auto_leave_allocation"/>
                    <div class="text-muted">
                        Automatic allocation of leave to the new employees.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//div[@id='default_company_schedule_setting']" position="inside">
                <div class="o_setting_left_pane">
                    <label for="holiday_status_id"/>
                    <div class="content-group">
                        <div class="mt16">
                            <field name="holiday_status_id" widget="many2many_tags" placeholder="Select Leave Type"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Comment: check you have added the 'hr_holidays' app in depends? hopping that all the file includes with odoo structure.

Comment: @Dipen Shah yea I have added the 'hr_holidays' module in depends.

'depends': [
        'hr_holidays', 'hr'],

Comment: I faced this error on production, whilst no issues on the local instance. For me, the solution was to add the "base" module into deps and restart odoo service . Then the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem, my solution is check where `holiday_status_id` was in your old odoo version, upgrade/reinstall that module in v14, it should resolve the issue